# how to get access to all the data in realm object server

Tags: realm, realm-object-server

basic conceptual question about realm.

I am looking at using realm for an ios project and would want to use realm object server which will be hosted.

But how do I mine and use that data held in the realm object server across all the user realms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can observe, access, and edit Realms using the Realm Browser. There's documentation here: https://realm.io/docs/realm-object-server/#the-realm-browser

I would also recommend doing the tutorial project (https://realm.io/docs/tutorials/realmtasks/) so you can get a better idea of how all the relevant components fit together.

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back to me Avi  - I guess that I will have to write an app that uses the admin token and some custom logic to integrate across the realms.  I have also found that I was just looking at the developer version too.  The facilitates that I was thinking might be there are in the professional and enterprise versions.  So fingers crossed the apps take off and I can afford them.